# How can I get MSBuild to stop overwriting newer versions of nuget dependencies with older ones?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I have a Visual Studio solution structured as follows:

- MyProject A with dependency:

  - NuGet Package 1, version irrelevant, with dependency:

    - NuGet Package 2, version >= 2.1.0.0
- MyProject B with dependency:

  - NuGet Package 2, version >= 6.0.0.0

If I build B, MSBuild copies NuGet Package 2 version 6.0.0.0 to the output directory (great).

If I then build A, MSBuild will overwrite NuGet Package 2 version 6.0.0.0 with version 2.1.0.0 and now MyProject B fails to load (not great) .

NuGet Package 1 is compatible with Package 2 version 6.0.0.0, so having that in the output directory is the best case as it works for both of my projects. How can I get MSBuild to stop overwriting newer (yet compatible) versions of dependencies with older versions?

Many thanks

Comment: How do A and B depend on each other? If they don't at all, then don't put their build output in the same place, as otherwise whichever one is compiled last will "win".

Comment: Project B depends on A. If I build B, it will first build A (putting version 2.1.0.0 of Package 2 in the output folder) and then B (will overwrite with version 6.0.0.0) and I guess that's fine for a full end-to-end build (like CI). But in a development situation where I've made a change to just A and only want to build A it ends up messing my output folder up. I guess that counts as a partial-rebuild of the overall solution, is this just unavoidable?

Comment: Do the two projects share output folder? Normally each project should have its own output folder, and any changes to Project A would require project B to be rebuilt. And if that is the case there should not be any problem, there should be no case where B is older than A.